# How to copy an uploaded csv file into a new csv file using SHINY?

Tags: r, csv, shiny

I want to copy the data from a CSV file uploaded by the user on the UI into another CSV file on my system. The data should be copied in the exact same manner. What should be done?

Comment: This question is quite broad as it stands. Do you know how to copy a file from a normal r session? (check `?file.copy`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

server.R:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  df_products_upload <- observeEvent(input$target_upload,{
    inFile <- input$target_upload
    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)
    file.copy(inFile$datapath, paste0(getwd(),"/data.csv"), overwrite = TRUE, recursive = FALSE,
              copy.mode = TRUE, copy.date = FALSE)
  })

}
)
```

ui.R

```
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  fileInput('target_upload', 'Choose file to upload',
            accept = c(
              'text/csv',
              'text/comma-separated-values',
              '.csv'
            ))

)
)
```

This copies the file to data.csv in your working directory. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hello once again Florian! I don't think the above code is working. The file is simply not being duplicated into another file. Data.csv is not getting creating also in my local system.

Comment: Strange, are you running it locally or on a server? It is working for me.

Comment: I modified the code, it now uses an observeEvent, the previous example was actually bad practice because I included a side-effect in a reactive.

Comment: THANK YOU FLORIAN! You are of great help

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.